# How to make list not repeat same character three times in row

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have this code

```
for letters in itertools.product(charset, repeat=47):
    string = "".join(letters)
    print(string)
```

and out from that is

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaab
aaaaaaaaaaac
```

but im wondering how can I make it not generate same three characters in row so that out put is

```
dddcccbbbaaa
dddcccbbbaab
dddcccbbbaac
```

and so on without using something like this

```
for letters in itertools.product(charset, repeat=47):
    string = "".join(letters)
    for i in range(1,len(string)-1):
        if string[i] is not string[i+1] is not string[i-1]:
            print(string)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: I don't understand: "how to make it not repeat the same character three times in a row", and then the desired result is `dddcccbbbaaa` where every character is repeated three times in a row!?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code:

```
import itertools

def version1(charset, N):
    result = []
    for letters in itertools.product(charset, repeat=N):
        string = "".join(letters)
        for i in range(0, N-2):
            if string[i] == string[i+1] == string[i+2]:
                break
        else: # did not find any ZZZ sequence
           result.append(string)
    return result

>>> charset = "abc"
>>> N = 5
>>> version1(charset, N)
['aabaa', 'aabab', 'aabac', 'aabba', 'aabbc', 'aabca', 'aabcb', 'aabcc', 'aacaa', 'aacab', 'aacac', 'aacba', 'aacbb', 'aacbc', 'aacca', 'aaccb', 'abaab', 'abaac', 'ababa', 'ababb', 'ababc', 'abaca', 'abacb', 'abacc', 'abbaa', 'abbab', 'abbac', 'abbca', 'abbcb', 'abbcc', 'abcaa', 'abcab', 'abcac', 'abcba', 'abcbb', 'abcbc', 'abcca', 'abccb', 'acaab', 'acaac', 'acaba', 'acabb', 'acabc', 'acaca', 'acacb', 'acacc', 'acbaa', 'acbab', 'acbac', 'acbba', 'acbbc', 'acbca', 'acbcb', 'acbcc', 'accaa', 'accab', 'accac', 'accba', 'accbb', 'accbc', 'baaba', 'baabb', 'baabc', 'baaca', 'baacb', 'baacc', 'babaa', 'babab', 'babac', 'babba', 'babbc', 'babca', 'babcb', 'babcc', 'bacaa', 'bacab', 'bacac', 'bacba', 'bacbb', 'bacbc', 'bacca', 'baccb', 'bbaab', 'bbaac', 'bbaba', 'bbabb', 'bbabc', 'bbaca', 'bbacb', 'bbacc', 'bbcaa', 'bbcab', 'bbcac', 'bbcba', 'bbcbb', 'bbcbc', 'bbcca', 'bbccb', 'bcaab', 'bcaac', 'bcaba', 'bcabb', 'bcabc', 'bcaca', 'bcacb', 'bcacc', 'bcbaa', 'bcbab', 'bcbac', 'bcbba', 'bcbbc', 'bcbca', 'bcbcb', 'bcbcc', 'bccaa', 'bccab', 'bccac', 'bccba', 'bccbb', 'bccbc', 'caaba', 'caabb', 'caabc', 'caaca', 'caacb', 'caacc', 'cabaa', 'cabab', 'cabac', 'cabba', 'cabbc', 'cabca', 'cabcb', 'cabcc', 'cacaa', 'cacab', 'cacac', 'cacba', 'cacbb', 'cacbc', 'cacca', 'caccb', 'cbaab', 'cbaac', 'cbaba', 'cbabb', 'cbabc', 'cbaca', 'cbacb', 'cbacc', 'cbbaa', 'cbbab', 'cbbac', 'cbbca', 'cbbcb', 'cbbcc', 'cbcaa', 'cbcab', 'cbcac', 'cbcba', 'cbcbb', 'cbcbc', 'cbcca', 'cbccb', 'ccaab', 'ccaac', 'ccaba', 'ccabb', 'ccabc', 'ccaca', 'ccacb', 'ccacc', 'ccbaa', 'ccbab', 'ccbac', 'ccbba', 'ccbbc', 'ccbca', 'ccbcb', 'ccbcc']
```

Your algorithm is not optimal. Look at the first string:

```
aaaaa
```

You know that you need `len(charset) - 1` iterations (`aaaab, aaaac`) to arrive to:

```
aaaba
```

And then again `len(charset) - 1` iterations to arrive to:

```
aaaca
```

But you can skip all those iterations, because of the `aaa` beginning.
Actually, when you find sequence `aaa`, you can skip `len(charset)^K - 1` where
`K` is the number of remaining chars. This does not change the big O complexity,
but will reduce the time of computation for long sequences, depending on the
size of the charset and the number of characters of the strings.

Intuitively, if the charset has few chars, you will spare a lot of computations.

First, you need to find the first letter after a ZZZ sequence:

```
def first_after_ZZZ(string):
     for i in range(0, len(string)-2):
         if string[i] == string[i+1] == string[i+2]:
             return i+3
     return -1

>>> first_after_ZZZ("ababa")
-1
>>> first_after_ZZZ("aaaba")
3
>>> first_after_ZZZ("aaabaaabb")
3
```

We use this function in the previous code (intermediate step):

```
def version2(charset, N):
    result = []
    for letters in itertools.product(charset, repeat=N):
        string = "".join(letters)
        f = first_after_ZZZ(string)
        if f == -1:
            result.append(string)
    return result

>>> version2(charset, N) == version1(charset, N)
True
```

Now, we can skip some elements:

```
def version3(charset, N):
    result = []
    it = itertools.product(charset, repeat=N)
    for letters in it:
        string = "".join(letters)
        f = first_after_ZZZ(string)
        if f == -1:
            result.append(string)
        elif f < N:
            K = N - f # K > 1
            to_skip = len(charset)**K-1 
            next(itertools.islice(it, to_skip, to_skip), None) # this will skip to_skip tuples
    return result

>>> version3(charset, N) == version1(charset, N)
True
```

Benchmark:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit as ti
>>> ti(lambda: version1(charset, 15), number=1)
13.14919564199954
>>> ti(lambda: version3(charset, 15), number=1)
6.94705574299951
```

This is impressive because the charset is small, but may be insignificant with a whole alphabet.

Of course, if you write your own implementation of `product`, you can skip the
tuples without generating them and this could be faster.

Comment: this is almost 2 times faster but when it comes to big charset it doesn't work because of sys.maxsize